# How to calculate MOSFET temperature increase in PCB

Tags: mosfet, pcb-design, heat, thermal

I want to calculate MOSFET([**DATASHEET**)](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/FDD86250_F085-D.PDF) temperature increase for PCB.

MOSFET - FDD86250_F085-D

Totally 13 MOSFET's will be mounted in PCB. At the same time, maximum 8 MOSFET's will be used in PCB

**1, Actual power dissipation for total MOSFET's?**

**2, Temperature increase in complete MOSFET(max. 8) in PCB?**

**3, Position of MOSFET's in PCB?**

**4, Will it require Heatsink?**

PCB size is 90(L)*62(W) mm

**From MOSFET Datasheet,**

Maximum Power Dissipation 160W

Operating Junction Temperature Tj - 55 to 175 °C

Thermal Resistance, Junction to Case Rthj c 0.94°C/W

Thermal Resistance, Junction to Ambient Rthj a 40°C/W 
[image]

Comment: "heat dissipation" isn't the correct term, use: "Power dissipation" and "temperature increase". From the information you provide, nothing meaningful can be calculated. You need to mention the **actual** power dissipation (total or per MOSFET), not the maximum power dissipation. If all MOSFETs would continuously dissipate 160 W you'd need a really large heatsink (and possibly a fan) to keep the MOSFETs cool.

Comment: What is your specific application? Is this pulsed power? Continuous? Are the devices paralleled? A schematic would be of great help here.

Comment: @PeterSmith I have added block diagram. Kindly help me to calculate power dissipation.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie yes correct. I have updated. And I want to calculate total MOSFET temperature increase.

Comment: standard thickness PCB foil (1 ounce/foot^2) has thermal resistance of 70 degree Centigrade per watt, flowing from edge to edge of the square, for any size square.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf  standard thickness can be taken for this calculation